# asp.net c# sample code library of comon tasks/ boiler plate code

Tags: asp.net

anyone use/ know of any library or website with code snippets or samples with many of the mundane boilerplate code and/ or functions like data access, data scrubbing, recursive routines...

preferably c# since most of .net in the real world is c#. VB is ok too.

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of good stuff (specifically for 'Data Access') in the Microsoft Patterns & Practices Enterprise Library [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx).  For scrubbing HTML and input from websites there's the Microsoft Web Protection Library (AntiXSS)  [here](http://wpl.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 2):

There is a bunch of snippets [here](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Code_Snippets) (CSharp Online).

Though, the best chance is to simply google/bing for the task you are trying to achieve - there are so many blogs and other sources of data (MSDN) out there. It's my first port of call.